# contract to contract transfer of fund error solidity

Tags: solidity

want to transfer funds from one contract to another

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.8.2;

contract pay {
    uint256 public value;
    uint256 public Val;
        
    function received() payable public returns (bool) {
        value = value.Add(msg.value).mul(95).div(100);
        Val = val.add(msg.value).mul(5).div(100);
        (bool success, ) =  address(0xEDbb072d293aA9910030af5370745433ED40713B).call{ value: value }("");
        require(success, " Error: Cannot send, voted against by holders"); 
        return true;
    }
    
    receive()  payable external {
        received();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I edited your question to make the code easier to read, and it seems that you have a typo preventing it from compiling (trying to access lowercase `val` instead of capitalized `Val`). Was this your issue, or do you need help with anything else? If it's anything else, please share the details of what goal you're trying to achieve, what kind of error are you getting, and most importantly - steps to reproduce the issue, so that others can help you find the answer to your question.

Comment: No I am able to transfer from contract to contract only if the recieving contract has plain fallback function. Of it's a contract like above, not able to send ether from another contract as it has function in fallback recieve like above code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not able to send ether directly from other contract to this constract

Comment: Value issue corrected working if send from metask, but unable to send from another contract

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is enough balance in the current contract.(contract pay)
check contract balance：

```
function getBalance() public view returns(uint){
   return address(this).balance;
}
```